# By whom and how was Eritrea sanctioned for having a citizenship-based taxation?

Tags: taxes, international, eritrea

I read on [20minutes.fr](https://www.20minutes.fr/economie/2301931-20180704-cauchemar-americains-accidentels-paient-impots-etats-unis-vivre-va-prendre-fin) ([mirror](http://archive.is/KBYb0)) that some French politicians are trying to pass a law exempting dual US+French citizens living in France from US taxes:

> « Le problème principal, c’est que la fiscalité américaine est basée sur la nationalité, en contradiction avec les règles de l’OCDE, estime l’eurodéputée française Virginie Rozière. L’Erythrée a voulu faire pareil et a été sanctionnée. Il n’y a pas de raisons de traiter les États-Unis différemment. Ils ne se comportent plus comme un grand frère bienveillant mais comme un acteur sans foi ni loi qui cherche le rapport de force. Si on n’est pas capable de répondre, on se fera écraser ».

Translation (based on [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%C2%AB%20Le%20probl%C3%A8me%20principal%2C%20c%E2%80%99est%20que%20la%20fiscalit%C3%A9%20am%C3%A9ricaine%20est%20bas%C3%A9e%20sur%20la%20nationalit%C3%A9%2C%20en%20contradiction%20avec%20les%20r%C3%A8gles%20de%20l%E2%80%99OCDE%2C%20estime%20l%E2%80%99eurod%C3%A9put%C3%A9e%20fran%C3%A7aise%20Virginie%20Rozi%C3%A8re.%20L%E2%80%99Erythr%C3%A9e%20a%20voulu%20faire%20pareil%20et%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20sanctionn%C3%A9e.%20Il%20n%E2%80%99y%20a%20pas%20de%20raisons%20de%20traiter%20les%20%C3%89tats-Unis%20diff%C3%A9remment.%20Ils%20ne%20se%20comportent%20plus%20comme%20un%20grand%20fr%C3%A8re%20bienveillant%20mais%20comme%20un%20acteur%20sans%20foi%20ni%20loi%20qui%20cherche%20le%20rapport%20de%20force.%20Si%20on%20n%E2%80%99est%20pas%20capable%20de%20r%C3%A9pondre%2C%20on%20se%20fera%20%C3%A9craser%20%C2%BB.)):

> "The main problem is that the US tax is based on nationality, in contradiction with OECD rules," said French MEP Virginie Rozière. "**Eritrea wanted to do the same and was sanctioned**. There is no reason to treat the United States differently. They no longer behave like a benevolent big brother, but as a faithless, lawless actor who pursues relations based on force. If we cannot respond, we will be crushed."

By whom and how was Eritrea sanctioned for having a citizenship-based taxation?

Answer (score 7):

The United Nations Security Council.

Eritrea has been [officially sanctioned](https://undocs.org/S/RES/1907(2009)) for supplying arms to Somalian terrorists and threatening Djibouti.

Eritrea has been [condemned](https://www.securitycouncilreport.org/atf/cf/%7B65BFCF9B-6D27-4E9C-8CD3-CF6E4FF96FF9%7D/Somalia%20S%20RES%202023.pdf) (part 10) for using a diaspora tax to further those efforts based on the [findings of the Somalia/Eritrea
Monitoring Group in its 18 July 2011 report (S/2011/433) (p101, Section D. Diaspora taxes and remittances)](https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/Full_Report_1869.pdf), and other nations are called upon (part 11) to thwart it to the full extent of their laws as part of the sanctions aimed at stability in the Horn of Africa region.

Comment: 11 is also relevant (regarding the means of collecting the tax, not the use that the money is put to).

Comment: Note that the resolution does *not* say anything about the fact that Eritrea taxes its citizens abroad, it deals with what Eritrea does with the money and the mode of collecting it.